# Debug gradle application on Netbeans

Tags: debugging, netbeans, gradle, dropwizard

I am able to run my application by executing it directly via Netbeans run command, but the application simply runs and no debug information is shown/captured.

Also, I need to pass some arguments to the main method, because I am using Dropwizard.

How can I debug my application on Netbeans?

Comment: Debuging works for me as well as running with Netbeans 8.0.2 and Gradle 2.4.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created the following task in `build.gradle`:

```
task(debug, dependsOn: 'classes', type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.example.MyMainClass'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    args 'server', 'my-application.yml'
    debug true
}
```

Netbeans runs the application and automatically connects to the debug port and starts debugging.

The 'args' line contains the arguments passed to the main method, needed by Dropwizard.

Based on [this article](https://coderwall.com/p/jwelaq).

Comment: Rather than explicitly set the JVM arguments you could just set the `debug` property on the [JavaExec](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:debug) task to `true`.

Comment: Nice suggestion, @MarkVieira. A lot clearer. I updated the answer. Thanks!